# Error: "E: Method https has died unexpectedly! E: Sub-process https received signal 4" during apt update on Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME

Tags: apt, 22.04, update-manager

I am encountering an issue while running the apt update command on my Ubuntu 22.04 system with GNOME desktop environment. I am receiving the following error message:

```
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received signal 4
```

I have checked my network settings, and HTTPS works fine in my web browser. I have also tried various solutions found online, including updating the ca-certificates package and modifying the OpenSSL configuration. However, none of these steps have resolved the issue.

Based on a suggestion I found in the Ubuntu community, I added the line "export GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1" to my .bashrc file and rebooted the system, but the error still persists.

I have reached out to the Ubuntu community for assistance, but I haven't received a working solution yet. Could someone please help me resolve this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
alias apt-get='GNUTLS_CPUID_OVERRIDE=0x1 apt-get'
```

It works within a session, but not as system command.